# How to link correctly X11 and GLIBC with node-gyp?

Tags: c, x11, glibc, dynamic-linking, node-gyp

Making a node.js C++ addon with `-lX11` and `-lXtst`. However, linking fails with an error.

```
Error: /snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6)
```

Answer (score 0):

> However, linking fails with an error.

Your build environment is failing basic sanity check.

You are trying to link your binary with *system* `libX11.so.6`, which was built against GLIBC-2.33 or later, and you are trying to link with an *alternate* (older) GLIBC located in  `/snap/core/current/lib`.

You need to use `libX11.so.6` that is *also* built against older version of GLIBC.

Comment: Yeah, I understand this. But what should I write `bindings.gyp` to link latest glibc? If i compile manually with `g++ ... -lX11 -lXtst`, everything works.

Comment: "what should I write ..." -- no idea. You need to find out where `/snap/core/current/lib` is coming from, and get rid of it (assuming the binary is to run on your own system).